# Applications of CO$_2$ sensors

Tags: sensors, gas, biomedical-engineering, air-quality, natural-gas

I am working on a project where I am creating a new type of CO<sub>2</sub> sensor. (I can't give details on the functionalities). I am looking for applications to showcase the capabilities and the usefulness of my sensor.

Description:

1. The size of the sensor is flexible. It can range from 10 cm<sup>3</sup> to 1 m<sup>3</sup>.
2. It can be implemented for air and water application.

Current Ideas:

1. Measure general CO<sub>2</sub> levels in an area (e.g. room, car, etc.) for safety.
2. Measure CO<sub>2</sub> levels when breathing for health status.

Any suggestions for innovative or common applications to demonstrate my CO<sub>2</sub> sensor capabilities?

Comment: Apollo 13 may give you an application.

Comment: Per the saying, "fast, cheap, good -- pick any two." Is your proposed sensor intended to be faster, cheaper, or better than current offerings? This will dictate applications. For example, in a lab you need accuracy, in a conference room you need something cheap.

Comment: For detecting the burning/combustion of carbon based materials. In horticulture where optimal CO2 levels are required for plant growth. Testing the exhaust of internal combustion engines. How much CO2 is produced by fossil fuel power stations.

Comment: canary in the coal mine?

Comment: How about closed-loop (rebreather) diving?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for co2 sensor for quite some time. Nothing cheap so far. Im interested in it for my room, to know when ventilation is needed. I see this as a main demand niche. 300-3000 ppm. Price needs to be below 10$.

Another one is for growing plants. They grow better at higher ppm. 1000-100 000 ppm. Price needs to be below 30$, but also humidity and temperature tolerant.